# How to change uploader of flutter package

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I have uploaded a package with an email and then I changed to another email. So in order to replace email I've added by using pub uploader add yyyy@gmail.com. and when I try to remove old email it displays the following error

`pub uploader remove  xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com`
**Self-removal is not allowed. Use another account to remove this email address.**

for this issue I searched to fix and found deleted .pub_cache/credentials.json will resolve but I cannot found that file in .pub-cache directory. I want to how to remove old email.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer by myself. Since there is no options like select uploader or logout pub authentication, we need revoke authentication in google. So that while publishing the package it will ask for authentication and that time we can provide new email. Let me explain all these.

First I uploaded a package to pub.dev by using xxxxx@gmail.com but I want to change to yyyyy@gmail.com. So inorder to do this, we have to add yyyyy@gmail.com to the package first. To do that

`pub uploader add yyyyy@gmail.com`

After adding in web browser go to my
account.google.com -> security -> manage third party access -> remove pub.dartlang.org.

after revoking access to old account in terminal publish the package again and it will ask for authentication, now login with yyyyy@gmail.com and then type

`pub uploader remove xxxxx@gmail.com`

Now changed the publisher successfully.

Comment: This is no longer supported, you cannot manage your plugins through the command line no more, you will need to go to https://pub.dev/packages/${YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME}/admin

Answer (score 0):

Right now the steps you mention above are generating the following error: `{"code":"MissingAuthentication","message":"authenication is required, please add authorization header."}`

For an updated approach do the following:

1. Add the new uploader with `flutter pub uploader add <new_email@email.com>`
2. Remove the previous uploader with `flutter pub uploader remove <previous_email@email.com>`
3. Remove saved credentials using `flutter pub logout` or `rm ~/Library/Application Support/dart/pub-credentials.json`.
4. Finally type `flutter pub publish` and allow access from your navigator.

Source: 
["flutter packages pub publish" fails #3037](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dev/issues/3037)

Answer (score 0):

Uploader and publisher of a package are no longer managed from the CLI. `$ pub uploader add yyyyy@email.com` command shows the message:

```
Package uploaders are no longer managed from the command line.
Manage uploaders from:

https://pub.dev/packages/<packageName>/admin
```